# Can't log in using observable and lazy loading

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and i'm trying to implementate a login functionality.

The problem is that after my user hits login it should storage the token and then redirect to the Home page, but the canActivate returns false.

Obs: I'm using observable cuz i need to hide my navBar in the login page, and the best way that i found is by using *ngIf and getting the value of isLoggedIn observable.

**AuthService.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { BaseService } from "./base.service";

@Injectable() 
export class AuthService extends BaseService{

private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

get isLoggedIn(){
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
}

constructor(http: HttpClient, private router : Router, private toastr : ToastrService) {
    super(http);
}

login(body: any){
    return this.post('User/login', body).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
          this.loggedIn.next(true);
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);                       
        },
        err => {
            if (err.status)
              this.toastr.error('FAIL!.');}
    )
}

logout(){
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn)
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';


@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

isLoggedIn$!: Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;

constructor(private router : Router, private authService : AuthService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
}

onLogout(){
 this.authService.logout();
}
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private router: Router, private toastr : ToastrService, private authService : AuthService) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean  {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          this.toastr.error("User not loged in!");
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard'; 

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "/login",
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'registration',
    loadChildren: () => import('./registration/registration.module').then(m => m.RegistrationModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove `AuthService` from `LoginModule`, because it creates another copy of this service in that module injector, and, because of that the other instance doesn't get the login state

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the `AuthService` as a singleton service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

Also remember that the `BehaviorSubject` emits the last value to new subscribers immediately